# Считывание строки

Tags: dos, c, gcc, строки

Правильно ли писать так?:

```
void main()
{
    char *path;
    scanf("%s", path);
}
```

В досовском компиляторе (qc2) работает без проблем, варнингов и ошибок. Да и препод сказал что правильно так писать, чем создавать статический массив.

Не было бы вопросов, если бы не одна незадача. В компиляторе gcc на этом моменте программа прерывается (ошибка сегментации).

Тут стоит уточнить: код выше тоже будет работать в gcc, однако, этот код уже неработоспособный:

```
void main()
{
    char *path;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    scanf("%s", path);
}
```

Почему в старом компиляторе всё в норме, а в современном - нет? Или всё-таки так писать неправильно?

---

UPD 1:

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), спасибо, прояснил.

[[@Janycz](/users/14422/janycz)](/users/14422/janycz), в данном случае вроде особой разницы нет, динамический или статический, ибо длина строки наперёд неизвестна.

А по сути, как в таком случае считывать строку, не зная её длину? Ведь создавать большой массив неразумно.

Comment: char *path указывает в никуда. Просто под досом компилятор этим не заморачивался, а Вам везло и туда, куда указывал path было доступно по чтению/записи и было безопасно. А ведь могло указывать где нибудь и в опасное место. И тогда бы долго удивлялись, почему системные часы меняются или принтер начинает печатать.

Современные компиляторы это дело просекают.

Вывод. Преподу подучится, старый компилятор просто недостаточно умный.

Comment: В C придется создавать большой массив. В С++ можно не создавать большой массив.

Comment: @froxxendsg а никак. Выделять буфер и внимательно следить за тем, чтобы `scanf` не вызвал переполнения (там есть возможность ограничить размер считываемой строки). Или делать самому считывание посимвольно и соответственно выделять память (правда, все равно памяти понадобится 2x длина считанной строки)

Comment: @froxxendsg, в Linux в такой ситуации используйте 

    ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);

см. `man 3 getline`.

Для винды напишите свой аналог (несколько десятков строк, хорошая тренировка).

Comment: Вот небольшой трактат по поводу того, как это делать правильно: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4874163/276994

Answer (score 1):

Для нового компилятора `char *path;` не строка, а указатель на один символ. Поэтому делайте статический массив или используйте `malloc`: `char *path = (char*)malloc(100);`

Comment: Для старого -- тоже. См. ответ @KoVadim.

Comment: Ну, не очень хороший совет. Пользователь введёт больше ста символов, и — бац! — срыв стека.

Вы думаете, откуда берутся эксплоиты? Вот из такого кода.

Comment: @VladD, ну, вряд ли вылетит по стеку, а вот структуры в куче попортятся и при следующих malloc/realloc/free (new/delete), и -- бац! -- segmentation fault.

Comment: @avp: «бац!» у меня не в смысле «программа обрушится», а «на ровном месте [дыра в безопасности](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)».